# Backup to URL Returns error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: sql-server

Hi Im trying to backup to url (blob storage). I have a deployment script that works perfectly on all of our local on-prem servers (deploys the credential etc), but as soon as it goes on our 1 azure VM i get a 403 error

> A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file. Backup to URL received an
> exception from the remote endpoint. Exception Message: The remote
> server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

The credentials must be ok as the script that created it works on our other servers.

Ive tried to log onto the VM and use Azure Blob Explorer to get to the storage account and it works fine (using the Key that is in the credential).

So I'm a bit at a loss, any ideas

This is the script to execute the backup

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Test]

TO URL = -------- 'Blob URL' ---------

WITH CREDENTIAL = 'Backup2Azure', FORMAT, COMPRESSION, SKIP, 
NO_CHECKSUM, STATS = 5
```

Comment: Which exact version is this server, and what about the servers that do work? `select @@version`

Comment: Both are Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5  Standard Edition